How can I get Wix studio website like stop while scrolling the section until the text reveal is complete?
Here, I am using html to show text reveal effect like Wix studio website https://www.wix.com/studio.
Please tell me how can I achieve the slight stop in the vertical scroll while I scroll the section having where the text reveal effect takes place. Below is the entire code.
I did try the text reveal effect and that's happening but I am not able to achieve the slight stop in the vertical scroll for the section. I need help with pausing the vertical scroll of the section.


const text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
const text2 = document.getElementById('text2');
const textContainer = document.querySelector('.text-container');

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const containerHeight = textContainer.clientHeight;

  if (scrollPosition > containerHeight * 0.3) {
    text1.classList.add('reveal');
  } else {
    text1.classList.remove('reveal');
  }

  if (scrollPosition > containerHeight * 0.5) {
    text2.classList.add('reveal');
  } else {
    text2.classList.remove('reveal');
  }
});

function adjustMobileView() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    text1.classList.add('reveal');
    text2.classList.add('reveal');
  } else {
    text1.classList.remove('reveal');
    text2.classList.remove('reveal');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', adjustMobileView);
window.addEventListener('load', adjustMobileView);
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  display: grid;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 150vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: stretch;
  justify-self: stretch;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 0 5% 5%;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: clip-path 1s ease-out;
}

.reveal {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.wrapper-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content max-content max-content auto;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0px, 1852.5fr);
  min-height: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 99.99976197212217%;
  top: calc(var(--is-sticky) * (var(--top) + var(--sticky-offset)));
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0.0010881274414849572%;
  margin-top: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <div class="text" id="text1">Your Headline Here</div>
        <div class="text" id="text2">Another Headline Here</div>
        <p>This is a para</p>
        <p>This is a para</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, fugiat deserunt ipsum et exercitationem minus aliquam omnis iusto! Molestiae doloremque modi aut provident? Iure dolores unde rem necessitatibus error vero!
  </p>
</div>




The text reveal effect is already there. But I want that the section does not scroll until the text reveal is complete. You see the slight stop in the scroll on website https://www.wix.com/studio while the text reveal is happening. I want this.
